# Is there a way to specify a certain range of numbers using array in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to add the first 20 numbers I generated randomly with an array in my script. Is this possible?

I used my previous script to generate 100 numbers and was hoping I could use it in this scenario as well. Now I need to add the first 20 using array. Could I incorporate a function into my script to solve this?

## Main Script

```
MAXCOUNT=100
count=1

while [ "$count" -le $MAXCOUNT ]; do
number[$count]=$RANDOM
let "count += 1"
done

echo "${number[@]}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop: `for ((count = 1; count <= maxcount; count++))` and you don't need to separately maintain your `count` variable. In numeric contexts such as the illustrated `for` statement and your array subscript, dollar signs aren't needed for variable names (however, if you were to use `$RANDOM` as an array subscript, you should use the dollar sign otherwise it gets evaluated twice). Don't use all-caps variable names in order to avoid the risk of name collisions with shell variables.

Answer (score 16):

I think you're asking how to get the first N elements of a bash array. If so, this should work:

```
$ array=( $(seq 1 30 ) )
$ echo ${array[@]}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
$ echo ${array[@]:0:20}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

The general format is `${array[@]:START:LENGTH}`. That will return the LENGTH next elements of array starting from START.

So, to add the first 20, you could do (note that I'm starting from 0, not 1 since arrays begin at 0. I suggest you correct your script and set `count=0` at the beginning instead of `count=1`; if you don't want to, change the `0` below to a `1`):

```
for i in ${number[@]:0:20}; do
    sum=$((sum + i))
done
echo $sum
```

Alternatively, you could just iterate over the first 20 elements of the array:

```
for((i=0;i<20;i++))
do
    sum=$(( sum + number[$i] ))
done
echo "$sum"
```

Both methods assume you are adding integers. Bash doesn't deal with floating point numbers so they will break if you try to add fractions. If that's an issue, use @hemayl's [clever trick](https://askubuntu.com/a/705131/85695) or any other program that can do math. For example:

```
echo "${number[@]:0:20}" | perl -lane '$k+=$_ for @F; print $k'
```

Comment: thanks..but why `"${number[@]:0:20}"` and `"${number[@]:1:20}"` produces the same result? is it something like if bash can't find value at index 0, it starts off counting from 1? i have tested with starting array at some other values and every time `0` is being replaced with the actual starting index

Comment: @heemayl it looks like it, yes. Apparently, bash will skip any indices that aren't defined. I haven't found any documentation that mentions it but I did confirm [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) that `array[N]=bar` needs `N` to be arithmetic and `declare -A` is needed for associative arrays. So, it looks like undefined indices are simply skipped.

Comment: In Bash: `array=( {1..30} )` (or , `(( sum += i ))` and `(( sum += number[i] ))`

Answer (score 5):

To add the first 20 numbers of the array `number`:

```
echo "${number[@]:0:20}" | tr ' ' '+' | bc
```

Or

```
tr ' ' '+' <<<"${number[@]:0:20}" | bc
```

- `"${number[@]:1:20}"` gets the first 20 elements of the array
- `tr ' ' '+'` converts all spaces into `+` so that we can use it as input to `bc` to get the addition done